# Live regular expression highlighting

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to use JavaScript to highlight regular expression matches in real time. Similar to sites such as http://regexr.com/

```
<p id="haystack"> Sample text Sample Text Sample Text Sample Text </p>

    <form>
      <input id="needle" onkeyup="highlight('haystack')" onkeydown="highlight('haystack')" type="text" placeholder="Enter Pattern" autofocus>
    </form>


function highlight(e){

    var pattern = document.getElementById('needle');

    var consoleText = document.getElementById('haystack').innerHTML;

    consoleText = consoleText.replace(pattern.value,"replaced");

    document.getElementById('haystack').innerHTML = consoleText;
```

I'm very new to JavaScript. How can I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function highlight(container,what,spanClass) {
    var content = container.innerHTML,
        pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + what + ')([^<.]*)','g'),
        replaceWith = '$1<span ' + ( spanClass ? 'class="' + spanClass + '"' : '' ) + '">$2</span>$3',
        highlighted = content.replace(pattern,replaceWith);
    return (container.innerHTML = highlighted) !== content;
}
```

Usage:

```
highlight(document.getElementById('content'),'hello','highlight');
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to be more specific in the future

Comment: Using `innerHTML` is evil!!! Use an existing plugin instead, like [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).